# Adding prefix to a primary key when inserted

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a table like this:

```html
reqnumber empname
   1       name1
   2       name2
```

Note that `reqnumber` is a primary key, and it auto increments for every insert and I wanted to add a prefix to it and then the number. Here's an example:

```html
reqnumber empname
  TS1      name1
  TS2      name2
```

I'm not really sure where to start because I don't have `reqnumber` on my insert code and I've read and tried some stuff but I can't really incorporate it to my insert code. Also, I'm using a dynamic form which kind of complicates my insert code even more.

Here's my insert code:

```js
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pcrequest");
if(isset($_POST["reqname"]))
{
 $length = 3;
 $trackingcode = 'TS-' . substr(str_shuffle("0123456789"), 0, $length);
 $req_date = $_POST["req_date"];
 $reqname = $_POST["reqname"];
 $date = $_POST["date"];
 $empname = $_POST["empname"];
 $position = $_POST["position"];
 $account = $_POST["account"];
 $platform = $_POST["platform"];
 $processor = $_POST["processor"];
 $ram = $_POST["ram"];
 $monitor = $_POST["monitor"];
 $phone = $_POST["phone"];
 $phonetype = $_POST["phonetype"];
 $headset = $_POST["headset"];
 $req_table = $_POST["req_table"];
 $req_chair = $_POST["req_chair"];
 $approval = $_POST["approval"];
 $status = $_POST["status"];
 $query = '';
 

  for($count = 0; $count<count($reqname); $count++)
  {
  $req_date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_date[$count]);
  $reqname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $reqname[$count]);
  $date_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $date[$count]);
  $empname_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $empname[$count]);
  $position_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $position[$count]);
  $account_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $account[$count]);
  $platform_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $platform[$count]);
  $processor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $processor[$count]);
  $ram_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $ram[$count]);
  $monitor_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $monitor[$count]);
  $phone_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phone[$count]);
  $phonetype_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $phonetype[$count]);
  $headset_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $headset[$count]);
  $req_table_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_table[$count]);
  $req_chair_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $req_chair[$count]);
  $approval_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $approval[$count]);
  $status_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $status[$count]);
  if($req_date_clean != '' && $reqname_clean != '' && $date_clean != '' && $empname_clean != '' && $position_clean != '' && $account_clean != '' && $platform_clean != '' && $processor_clean != '' && $ram_clean != '' && $monitor_clean != '' && $phone_clean != '' && $phonetype_clean != '' && $headset_clean != '' && $req_table_clean != '' && $req_chair_clean != '' && $approval_clean != '' && $status_clean != '')
  {
   $query .= '
   INSERT INTO request(trackingcode, req_date, reqname, date, empname, position, account, platform, processor, ram, monitor, phone, phonetype, headset, req_table, req_chair, approval, status) 
   VALUES("'.$trackingcode.'", "'.$req_date_clean.'", "'.$reqname_clean.'", "'.$date_clean.'", "'.$empname_clean.'", "'.$position_clean.'", "'.$account_clean.'", "'.$platform_clean.'", "'.$processor_clean.'", "'.$ram_clean.'", "'.$monitor_clean.'", "'.$phone_clean.'", "'.$phonetype_clean.'", "'.$headset_clean.'", "'.$req_table_clean.'", "'.$req_chair_clean.'", "'.$approval_clean.'", "'.$status_clean.'"); 
   ';
  }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is the current result of your code? What is the desired result? If you are getting errors, include the exact error message in your question.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to add a prefix to a PK? Usually numeric keys are faster in a database, while text keys are slower. You can do binary search with numbers, while text requires a linear scan or in this case (since it's a PK) the RDBMS is likely going to keep an index of the column, which means faster retrieval but overhead on adding/removing entries as it re-indexes.

Comment: Just add the `TS` string to the value when you read it back from the database.

Comment: @PatrickQ Hmm I'm not really getting any errors, I just want to know how to do that.

Comment: @VLAZ I wanted to make my primary key which is the reqnumber as a "trackingcode". As you can see, I tried creating a "trackingcode" column but I can't do increment, I can only make it generate random numbers

Comment: @Nick What do you mean? Add the TS in the form?

Comment: @IamV when you display the value, rather than `echo $row['reqnumber'];` (or similar) just `echo 'TS' . $row['reqnumber'];` instead

Comment: a tracking_number should always be random, and even more so if you are going to relate that tracking_number to a row of information in your database, that way when a guest, customer needs to look up a order, tracking_number they can only view the row of data that relates to their unique tracking_number. Why am I telling you this, because I have seen people do things like you are wanting to do, and then they end up allowing others to access other peoples order information all because they used only sequenced based tracking_number(s) to keep other peoples private data safe...

Answer (score 0):

As your column is with AUTO_INCREMENT it has to be of an integer or floating type (any size).
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

> Some attributes do not apply to all data types. AUTO_INCREMENT applies
>   only to integer and floating-point types.

So you can't assign it a string value.
You can add a new column and fill it using a trigger to generate and insert the value you want (content would be build at insert time).
or you can create a view to access it (content will be evaluated each time you query it).